# Python seaborn kdeplot looks very different than same density curve with R?

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, seaborn

[image: Python Density Plot]
My code for this Python plot was:

```
data = pd.read_csv(output_file)

sns.kdeplot(data['length'], shade=True)

plt.show()
```

[image: R Density Plot]

My code for this R plot was:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=length)) + geom_density(alpha=.4, fill='blue') + xlim(0,2000)
```

Why are these plots so different?

The maximum goes to about 0.005 in R, while in Python it is about 1.4 * 10^-9. For the Python plot, when I add an argument limiting the x-values from 0 to 2000, the density line barely lifts above .01*10^-9.

This is the head of my data['length'] in case that might be helpful:

```
0      46
1     367
2     887
3     346
4     431
5      28
6     266
7    1051
8     257
9      31
```

I suspect this may have something to do with the bandwidth for the  python plot, however when I manipulate the bandwidth the problem does not fix itself. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: [`geom_density`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_density.html) is "a smoothed version of the histogram"

Comment: So how can I make the Python plot more smoothed? I assumed with a higher bandwidth, but when I do this the plot gains negative x values (there are no negative values in the csv).

Comment: have you tried plotting with `sns.densplot()`? that’s probably going to produce a more similar looking plot.

Comment: [`kdeplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) has an important parameter `bw=` to control the bandwidth. Setting it to a higher number results in a smoother plot. Some experimentation or good knowledge about the underlying distribution is needed.